# WPF ListView/GridView Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, visual-studio-extensions

I am attempting to make a simple VS 2017 Extension that is taking a object and displaying it. I have the data coming back and displaying the json in a text box, so I know the data is coming back correctly. But for some reason the gv is just showing the word "id" twice, as their are two records in the dataset. I have tried so many things I'm loosing track. Plus the documentation seems to be all over the place.

I believe there could be at least 2 issues here...

1) XAML the "Bindings"

2) Binding or adding the data to the LV?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

XAML

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="DoWork.AllWorkVSControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             Background="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"
             Foreground="{DynamicResource VsBrush.WindowText}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="MyToolWindow">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">AllWorkVS</TextBlock>
            <Button Content="Click me!" Click="button1_Click" Width="120" Height="80" Name="button1"/>
            <TextBox Height="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtJson"/>
            <ListView x:Name="LvIssues">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Id"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source='Id'}"></GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#

---

```
public class People
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public partial class AllWorkVSControl : UserControl
{

    public AllWorkVSControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = Issues.GetPeopleById("2");
        PopulateListView();
        MessageBox.Show(t);
    }

    private void PopulateListView()
    {
        var l = GetPeople();
        txtJson.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);

        foreach (var p in l)
        {
            LvIssues.Items.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for cutting down the code, but you cut out what we needed to see. Need to see where you're setting the window's DataContext, what are you setting it to, and the visual tree from the window to your listview.

Comment: @Will i updated the xaml part. I dont have a window.datacontext. perhaps that is my problem. I am trying to find the "Visual Tree" now.

Comment: PopulateListView- Where is this function exists?

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian inside the DoWork.xaml.cs. its fired from the a click on the window. I've tried to update the above more.

Comment: The visual tree is what you write in XAML. At runtime, that's compiled and instantiated and the result is called the logical tree, as it is often very different than the XAML. Also, Snoop is a good tool for examining your bindings at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the ListView.ItemsSource.

```
private void PopulateListView()
{
    var l = GetPeople();
    txtJson.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);

    LvIssues.ItemsSource= l;
}

<ListView x:Name="LvIssues">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Id"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"></GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: that seems to yield the same result. I think i'm missing something on the XAML part? Maybe the DisplayMemberBinding?

Comment: that was it. I know i tried that before, something else must of been off! Thanks so much!