# Using data binding in custom tool window's user control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to create a visual studio extension that contains a custom tool window and use data binding for the `UserControl` within the custom tool window but it seems like the `UserControl`'s `DataContext` changes between the `UserControl`'s instantiation and when data bindings are evaluated.

This is the code that should create the custom tool window with and the `UserControl` with the good `DataContext`. (it's within the command execution handler)

```
object futureDataContext = new object();  
YourUserControl toolWindowContent = new YourUserControl() { DataContext = futureDataContext };
// 0 for single instance tool window and true to create if it doesn't already exists
ToolWindowPane window = package.FindToolWindow(typeof(YourCustomToolWindow), 0, true);
window.Content = toolWindowContent;
```

My custom tool window's constructor looks like this :

```
// : base(null) has been auto generated at the file's creation
public CustomTooWindow() : base(null)
{
    // I have figured out that if this.Content isn't set when exiting the constructor we get a COM exception.
    // I'm assuming it's because Visual Studio must have something to display right after the custom tool window instantiation.
    this.Content = new YourUserControl();
}
```

All i know so far :

> -It seems like the instance of the custom tool window returned by `package.FindToolWindow()...` and the instance being used by Visual Studio for real aren't the same.
>
> -If you set the `DataContext` of `YourUserControl` within the `CustomToolWindow`'s constructor it is kept
>
> -If i register to `DataContextChanged` right after creating the `UserControl`'s instantiation (in the command handler not it `CustomToolWindow`'s constructor) it is never triggered.

How could I have the good `DataContext` on my `UserControl` for sure?

**EDIT :**

I found a workaround but it's not really pleasing : in CustomToolWindow class I added this :

```
public static CustomToolWindow CurrentWindow { get; private set; }

public override void OnToolWindowCreated()
{
    CurrentWindow = this;
    base.OnToolWindowCreated();
}

public void SetContentDataContext(object newDataContext)
{
    if (Content is FrameworkElement element)
    {
        element.DataContext = newDataContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check if [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274096/wpf-listview-gridview-binding) can help.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT this issue doesn't talk about the data contexts

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like the instance of the custom tool window returned by package.FindToolWindow()... and the instance being used by Visual Studio for real aren't the same.

Do you mean each time you call code below you get a different instance?

```
ToolWindowPane window = package.FindToolWindow(typeof(YourCustomToolWindow), 0, true);
```

As for DataContext change you mention between your control instantiation and data binding, where do you set control's DataContext since you don't pass any parameters in the usercontrol constructor below.

```
// : base(null) has been auto generated at the file's creation
public CustomTooWindow() : base(null)
{
    // I have figured out that if this.Content isn't set when exiting the constructor we get a COM exception.
    // I'm assuming it's because Visual Studio must have something to display right after the custom tool window instantiation.
    this.Content = new YourUserControl();
}
```

Comment: About the instance changing i dont know atm, i'll get back to you when i know. About where the datacontext is being set, check the first code snippet in my question, it is set at the second line with `YourUserControl toolWindowContent = new YourUserControl() { DataContext = futureDataContext }` `futureDataContext` being anything you want to have as DataContext (see line above in my question snippet)